# Injection of more beans into one method in Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0

The example 3.16 in [Jersey chapter 3](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2435) shows that it's possible to inject more beans in a resource method:

```
@POST
public void post(@BeanParam MyBeanParam beanParam, @BeanParam AnotherBean anotherBean /*other params*/) {
    ...
}
```

But it doesn't show any URI pattern for `@Path` annotation to access the method.

In particular I need to implement a `GET` service for multiple beans and access their query parameters, like so:

```
@GET
public Response post(@BeanParam MyBeanParam beanParam, @BeanParam AnotherBean anotherBean /*other params*/) {
   // process query params and return something
}
```

The URI should look like this, I guess:

```
http://[host]/mybeanparam?param1=v1&param2=v2/anotherbean?param1=v3
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use rest style for parameters.

Comment: @nikpon Are you referring to the URI? I think it's REST-compliant.